# How to convert a link to a base_url link to delete a row from the data base table using id, in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My base Url is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/VI/';
```

currently I am using
                                                                                `<a href="<?php echo "http://localhost/VI/admin/deleteMainSlider?id=".$row->id ?>"</a>`
link to delete an item from the table using id.

And my need is that how can I include my **base_url** to above link? How can i make it as a **base_url** form?

Comment: `<a href="<?php echo base_url()."admin/deleteMainSlider?id=".$row->id ?>"</a>`

Comment: thank u so much. its working. am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add  `base_url` as

```
<?php echo base_url("admin/deleteMainSlider?id=".$row->id);?>
```

It is created as

```
base_url("controller/function);
```